# How can I swap Super and Ctrl *except* in Terminal?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, macosx

As a 10+ year OS X refugee using Ubuntu 14.04, I'm trying to get my keyboard set-up as close to OS X as possible, and I'm actually using the Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad (and have already found this resource: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard ).

Swapping the Control and Command keys using `xmodmap` has gotten me 95% of the way to where I want to be -- many shortcuts line up reasonably well in many GUI apps, including cut, copy, paste, find, etc -- *but* the GNOME Terminal is all wrong. What I'd like to do is have it work like OS X's Terminal, where the physical Command key, paired with -C, -X, -V, etc invoke commands in the application, and the physical Control key behaves like a standard (i.e. VT-100 style) control key.

In other words: I want the physical Command and Control keys switched for every application **except** GNOME Terminal.

Xmodmap seems to be "all or nothing." I've tried various approaches with `gconf-editor`, `evrouter` and `AutoKey`, all to no avail so far (not to mention infuriating to debug, with the key mappings all jacked up.) I was about to go off and see about compiling my own slightly-modified version of `GNOME Terminal` but figured I'd see if anyone had any hot ideas on how to get this *juuuust* right.

Comment: FWIW, for the time being, I've managed to beat AutoKey into submission and get it to do what I want in GNOME Terminal, that said, it's supremely clunky, so if anyone has a better way I'd still love to hear it. I put my AutoKey Phrases into a Gist if anyone's interested: https://gist.github.com/ipmcc/5f1f17a7b0107f165f72608882a7657f

Comment: after 6 years, I haven't found a solution. It seems you are the only one talking about this problem. Could you explain to me how to set up the autoKey phrases? I have tried it but I am not familiar with the application.

Comment: While AutoKey can do this, you might have to write a lot of phrases because it won't just swap modifier keys. And, IIUC, what you want is a negative window filter (affect all windows, except ...). Negative window filters are a PITA in AutoKey because of a design flaw in AutoKey that we haven't managed to get fixed yet. To discuss this in detail, join us over on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey).